# Python error when create super class : "TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters"

Tags: python, runtime-error, super

I'm modifying the script from https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/jetbot/blob/master/jetbot/robot.py removing the trailets library as its not needed for my purpose.  I'm now receiving the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ak_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    robot = Robot()
  File "/home/jetbot/jetbot/jetbot/robot.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.left_motor = Motor(self.motor_driver, channel=self.left_motor_channel, alpha=self.left_motor_alpha)
  File "/home/jetbot/jetbot/jetbot/motor.py", line 14, in __init__
    super(Motor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # initializes traitlets
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

I've coppied the relevent bits of the code below  that will replicate the issue:

```
   import time
from Adafruit_MotorHAT import Adafruit_MotorHAT

class Motor():

    value = float()
    
    # config
    alpha = float(1.0)
    beta = float(0.0)

    def __init__(self, driver, channel, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Motor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # initializes traitlets
        self._driver = driver
        self._motor = self._driver.getMotor(channel)
        if(channel == 1):
            self._ina = 1
            self._inb = 0
        else:
            self._ina = 2
            self._inb = 3
        atexit.register(self._release)
        
    def _observe_value(self, change):
        self._write_value(change['new'])

    def _write_value(self, value):
        """Sets motor value between [-1, 1]"""
        mapped_value = int(255.0 * (self.alpha * value + self.beta))
        speed = min(max(abs(mapped_value), 0), 255)
        self._motor.setSpeed(speed)
        if mapped_value < 0:
            self._motor.run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.FORWARD)
            # The two lines below are required for the Waveshare JetBot Board only
            self._driver._pwm.setPWM(self._ina,0,0)
            self._driver._pwm.setPWM(self._inb,0,speed*16)
        else:
            self._motor.run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.BACKWARD)
            # The two lines below are required for the Waveshare JetBot Board only
            self._driver._pwm.setPWM(self._ina,0,speed*16)
            self._driver._pwm.setPWM(self._inb,0,0)

    def _release(self):
        """Stops motor by releasing control"""
        self._motor.run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.RELEASE)
        # The two lines below are required for the Waveshare JetBot Board only
        self._driver._pwm.setPWM(self._ina,0,0)
        self._driver._pwm.setPWM(self._inb,0,0)


class Robot():
    
    left_motor = Motor
    right_motor = Motor

    i2c_bus = 1
    left_motor_channel = 1
    left_motor_alpha = 1.0
    right_motor_channel = 2
    right_motor_alpha = 1.0
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Robot, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.motor_driver = Adafruit_MotorHAT(i2c_bus=self.i2c_bus)
        self.left_motor = Motor(self.motor_driver, channel=self.left_motor_channel, alpha=self.left_motor_alpha)
        self.right_motor = Motor(self.motor_driver, channel=self.right_motor_channel, alpha=self.right_motor_alpha)
        
    def set_motors(self, left_speed, right_speed):
        self.left_motor.value = left_speed
        self.right_motor.value = right_speed
        
    def forward(self, speed=1.0, duration=None):
        self.left_motor.value = speed
        self.right_motor.value = speed

    def backward(self, speed=1.0):
        self.left_motor.value = -speed
        self.right_motor.value = -speed

    def left(self, speed=1.0):
        self.left_motor.value = -speed
        self.right_motor.value = speed

    def right(self, speed=1.0):
        self.left_motor.value = speed
        self.right_motor.value = -speed

    def stop(self):
        self.left_motor.value = 0
        self.right_motor.value = 0

robot = Robot()
```

Comment: `Motor` extends `object`, which takes no arguments to its constructor. What were you trying to do? What traitlets do you think you're going to initialize, and how?

Comment: When you're a subclass of `object`, you don't need to call the `__init__` method.  Or if you do, call it without arguments.

Comment: Get rid of the `super().__init__()` part. Your `Motor` class does not extend anything meaningful, so there is nothing to `__init__`.

Comment: In your own words, when you write `super(Motor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`, what do you think that means? In your own words, what do you think is the base class of `Motor`? In your own words, how do you think instances of that class should be initialized? In your own words, when you write `def __init__(self, driver, channel, *args, **kwargs):` for the `Motor` class, what kinds of values do you expect `args` and `kwargs` to have? What do you think should be done with those values?

Comment: If you didn't understand those things - for example, because you're working in a new language, and modifying someone else's code - then as a ten-year user of Stack Overflow, you should understand by now how to do some [research, as expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). For example, you could try looking up `super` [itself](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+super).

Answer (score 1):

When you call `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`, you are passing ***all*** unnamed parameters to the parent class's `__init__`.  In your case, the parent class is **`object`** which doesn't take any parameters.

In the **`Robot.__init__`** you pass `alpha` as a keyword argument to **`Motor.__init__`**, which gets bound to **`kwargs`**, hence your error.

To fix this, you need to deal with `alpha` in **`Robot.__init__`**:

```
class Motor:
    def __init__(self, driver, channel, *args, alpha=None, **kwargs):
        super(Motor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        ...
```